Some concerns about using "a subset $X$ of a metric space is closed if and only if every convergent sequence in $X$ has their limit in $X$ "
I've seen this proof and I have some concerns about using this theorem
In some questions, we know the given set $X$ is closed
Based on the information given that $X$ is closed, is that always admissible to claim " considering an arbitrary convergent sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ with its limit $x^*\in X$"
I am wobbling about this claim because the theorem says every convergent sequence converges within the space. Given an arbitrary $x^*\in X$, what if there is no sequence in $X$ converges to $x^*$

Well, given an $x^\ast \in X$, there is certainly a sequence in $X$ converging to $x^\ast$, namely the constant sequence $(x^\ast,x^\ast,x^\ast,\cdots)$. But this is true for open sets as well (and those which are neither open nor closed). What matters is whether you pick the point first or the sequence first. If you pick the sequence $(x_n)$ first, and you know it has a limit (not all sequences have limits), AND you know $X$ is closed, then you know for sure that $\lim x_n \in X$.

When discussing the topolocgical space represented by $~\Bbb{C},~$ according to Theorem 1.9 of chapter 2 - section 1 of "An Introduction To Complex Function Theory" by Bruce Palka, the assertion in the posted question is not quite accurate.  Theorem 1.9 states that The subset $~A~$ of $~\Bbb{C}~$ is closed if and only if $~A~$ contains every accumulation point of every sequence in $~A.~$  Therefore, Theorem 1.9 is inconsistent with the assertion.

Now comes the fun part.  You have to prove that The subset $~A~$ contains every accumulation point of every sequence in $~A~$ if and only if every convergent sequence in $~A~$ has their limit in $~A.~$  If I understand correctly, this is provable, and therefore the assertion in the posted question is in fact accurate.  If you have a convergent sequence, then the limit of the sequence is an accumulation point.  Conversely, if you have an accumulation point, there must exist a convergent (sub)sequence for which the accumulation point is the limit.

My previous comments beg two questions: [1] To what extent is the analysis extendible from $~\Bbb{C}~$ to any topological space $~Y~$ for which $~X~$ might be a subset?  [2] Does your topological education include (in effect) either a proof of Theorem 1.9, or analysis that will lead to a proof of Theorem 1.9?

@user2661923 The exact theorem given by the lecturer is  "Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Then $A$ is closed iff the limit of every convergent sequence in $A$ is still in $A$".

@PrincessEev Thank you for your reply. if a question goes like  "Given a $A\subset X$, (we don't know $A$ closed or not, we only know it is well ordered).   If I say: consider a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n\to \sup{A}$".  is this a valid claim? If so, why?

To LJNG : The point of my comments is that it may or may not be easier to prove Theorem 1.9, on your generic topological space, than it is to prove (from scratch) your posted theorem/assertion.  It depends on what pertinent math theory, in the form of previous theorems, worked examples, or solved problems, that you have been taught, that led up to the posted theorem/assertion.

In a comment you write that you are working in a metric space. You should edit your question to include this essential information. As it is, your question is unclear.

@PaulFrost Thank you for your reply. If provided metric space condition, would you please enlighten me more about my question assertion


the theorem says every convergent sequence converges within the space.

Correct.

Given an arbitrary $x^*\in X$, what if there is no sequence in $X$ converges to $x^*$

Of course the constant $x^*$ sequence is a sequence in $X$ convergent to $x^*$. But actually it is not relevant, the theorem doesn't say that every point has to be a limit point of some (special or not) sequence. It only says that if a sequence converges, then it converges in $X$.

Thank you for your answer. Is there any relevant theorem say anything about "every point in the space will be the limit for some sequence in the space"
